# Docker Server for Multiple Users

Tags: linux, security, docker

I am planning on installing Linux on a high end PC with a GPU in my lab, with the intention of allowing students and other researchers to run Docker containers when they need a bit of extra performance.

I do not want each of these users to have root access (which, as far as I understand, is required to launch Docker containers). I prefer that a given student does not need to even have a user account on this server to run a Docker container. I also do not want to create a VM for running the containers.

In a perfect world, I would set up a Docker volume locally on the server for each individual. When they launch a Docker container, they can only mount their specific directory. Essentially, I have two questions.

1. Can I set such a system up where I restrict the path for volumes when running a Docker image?
2. Is there a way to set this up so individuals can remotely launch their Docker images without needing a local user account?

Comment: This question is not about programming. I am voting to migrate it to serverfault, but it may also be OK under the security.stackexchange.org site.

Comment: As a pseudo-answer, what you want is impossible to achieve securely. Anyone who can upload an image can upload an "evil" image. There is no way to allow only "wholesome" images. You may be lucky using AppArmor/SELinux to deny access to certain paths - but this is certainly not a well-suported, safe usage scenario.

Comment: That was what I was afraid of. It seems like the best way to keep the server secure is to create a VM specifically for this purpose. I was hoping to avoid this added complexity, given that I want to share access to the GPU, but it shouldn't be insurmountable. Thank you for the pseudo-answer!

Comment: Openshift from Redhat supports multi-tenancy, isolating user workloads from each other and controlling what users are allowed to do (for example running privileged containers). It's based on Kubernetes which is a bit more complicated to setup when compared to Docker Swarm

Comment: Thank you for the comment Mark. I'll definitely look into Openshift, it looks very interesting.